# All packages are not available for download! The following packages are not available: - Package id emulatorI am Trying To Run my virtual device ,

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation

I Have Created My Virtual Device,But When I Click On Run,It shows Error That "Intel HAXM is required to run this AVD.
No emulator installed
[Intel Haxm Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2cIA.png)

Please download the emulator"
And When I Click On OK IT shows -
"All packages are not available for download!  The following packages are not available:
- Package id emulator",
[Package Id EMulator Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcj8e.png)

I Have Download Intel HAXM From Both Android Studio And "https://github.com/intel/haxm"
But Then Also It Shows The Same Error.

Please Help Me With How TO Solve This.
Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue before.
To solve it, I just restarted the Android Studio and try again.
Then the emulator was installed.

Comment: I have tried restarting it but then also. It shows the same error